# Finding words that a player says & block it

Tags: c++

I am wondering how to basically make the player's sentence stop after it has a swear word in it. Now, I have it already setup, BUT I need to know how to use the tolower method and how to stop it from saying the same word 3 times in a row while using this for loop:

```
std::size_t found;
std::string word[3] = { "swear", "swear1", "swear2" };
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
   found = msg.find(word[i]); // needs to have tolower
   if(found != std::string::npos)
   {
      SendNotification("Message blocked. Does it contain swearing?");
      return;
   }
   else
   {  
      GetPlayer()->Say(msg, lang);
   }
}
```

Help would be grateful!

Comment: What is player (character in a game?), what library are you using (for the database, are you really going to consult a database everytime someone says something? What is the class definition of fields... More detail is needed.

Comment: Is the result of CharacterDatabase.Query the collection of all words to filter? Does res->NextRow() cause the next word to be returned by the next res->Fetch()? Does res->NextRow() return true if there are words remaining in res?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a SQL database for this? It would probably be faster to just have a `std::map` of words and check each word to see if it's in the map.

Comment: If it is what I am thinking above, you are much better off store the expletives in memory once by extracting them from whatever that fields type is.

Comment: @EdF: Next row consists of MYSQL_ROW row,  row = mysql_fetch_row(m_result). CharacterDatabase.Query is the query that selects the words from the database and puts it into msg.find(field[0].GetString()); I'm certain I'd like to use a database for this, but if there is an easier way, then I'd like to know.

Comment: So am I allowed to say I multiclASSed as an ASSASSin?  Also, learn from Runescape.  People will just swap $ for S and similar to bypass this.

Comment: Perhaps, but I can easily change that though. Assassin is a word, not a swear word.

Comment: @TommyCooper: Be careful of the [Scunthorpe problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem). Filters like these are notorious for being unreliable because of it.

Comment: @TommyCooper: Or two swear words. http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The-Clbuttic-Mistake-.aspx

Comment: @Insilico: That isn't an issue for me to worry about. When players are ingame, they should just chat, not give out emails and/or links.

Comment: @TommyCooper: Also note that although Assassin is not a swear word, your code will treat it like one.  That's what I meant, and Insilico, and FredLarson...

Answer (score 2):

The reason it is only blocking the first word, is because you are `Say()`ing the message inside the `else` block as soon as the first word is not matched. Keep a variable `bool badWordFound = false` **before** the start of the loop and set it true inside the `if(...){ }` block. Then, after checking all the words, if `badWordFound == true` display your warning, `else Say()`

```
set found to false
for each swear word
    if found in the sentance
        set found to true
if found is false
    display sentance
else
    display warning
```

HTH

Edit: Also, the comments about caching the filter list in memory are worth following up on if this is anything more than an exercise.

Comment: I updated the code. I'm wanted to try something different now.

Comment: My advice remains the same, you still are calling `Say()` every time a word is not matched, not to mention a few other problems like dereferencing word[3] to word[7] in a length 3 array

Comment: Whoops, well, I have 8, so I just changed it up a bit. Anyway, could you elaborate with example code?